# How arrange data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame which contains Product_Id and FrontOfficeUser_Id.

```
     Data_Achat=data.frame(ID_Achat,ID_Prod)
    > Data_Achat[1:10,]
   ID_Achat ID_Prod
1      1349     433
2      1349     405
3      1349     451
4      4890     405
5      4890     405
6      4890     416
7      4890     416
8      4890     388
9      4890     464
10     4890     416
```

Then I want to  get a new data frame showing in each line the ID_Achat and its corresponding ID_Prod. In other word, for this example I want to get like this:

```
1 1349  433 405 451 
2 4890  405 405 416 416 388 464 416
```

How can I get this results ?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is perhaps `split(df$ID_Prod, df$ID_Achat)` though that creates a list instead of a data.frame. Why do you want such a format in a data.frame in the first place?

Comment: Thanks  docendo discimus,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to put your data in a data.frame:

```
split_data <- split(df$ID_Prod, df$ID_Achat)
pasted <- lapply(split_data,paste,collapse=" ")
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,pasted))
                              V1
1349                 433 405 451
4890 405 405 416 416 388 464 416
```

**EDIT**

Here's how to get back the ID column:

```
split_data <- split(df$ID_Prod, df$ID_Achat)
pasted <- lapply(split_data,paste,collapse=" ")
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,pasted))
df_final <- cbind(ID_Achat=rownames(df),df)
colnames(df_final)[2] <- "ID_Prod"
df_final

     ID_Achat                     ID_Prod
1349     1349                 433 405 451
4890     4890 405 405 416 416 388 464 416
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre Lapointe, But How can I extract the first colums of the data?? Because I need the Id of custumer

Comment: @lmed I edited my answer to add an ID column. Basically, you get it from the row names.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre has a great answer. If you want each of those to be its own column, you can use this as well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data_Achat %>% 
      group_by(ID_Achat) %>% 
      mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      spread(rn, ID_Prod)
```

edit:

```
Data_Achat <- data.frame(ID_Achat = c(rep(1349, 3), rep(4890, 7)), ID_Prod = c(433, 405, 451, 405, 405, 416, 416, 388, 464, 416))

    Data_Achat2 <- Data_Achat %>% 
+     group_by(ID_Achat) %>% 
+     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
+     ungroup() %>% 
+     spread(rn, ID_Prod)

    > Data_Achat2[1,]
# A tibble: 1 x 8
  ID_Achat   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1349   433   405   451    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but the probleme here is in manipulating the data frame ! for example if i want Data_Achat[1,] it gives: ID_Achat ID_Prod
1     1349     433 . But I want like : 1     1349   433   405   451

Comment: It does do that. It adds the NAs as well though not sure if you want to be able to do anything with those and want them all in one column. 
`Data_Achat <- data.frame(ID_Achat = c(rep(1349, 3), rep(4890, 7)), ID_Prod = c(433, 405, 451, 405, 405, 416, 416, 388, 464, 416))`

then:
`Data_Achat2 <- Data_Achat %>% 
+     group_by(ID_Achat) %>% 
+     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
+     ungroup() %>% 
+     spread(rn, ID_Prod)`

then:
`Data_Achat2[1,]`

Comment: I think the original code I posted it didn't overwrite the dataframe.